# Sequelize throwing invalid input syntax for integer ""

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I've got a model definition here:

```
const Tags = sequelize.define('Tag', {
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    adminOnly: {
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        defaultValue: false,
    },
})
```

And 2 endpoints which create and fetch objects from the DB (psql)

```
const tags = await Tags.findAll()
```

But this line fails. What i get is

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeDatabaseError: invalid input syntax for integer: "tags"
```

While

```
await Tag.create({name: name, isStock: isStock ?? false})
```

works perfectly fine.

When i log in to the psql console and do select over the table i have no problems either.

Answer (score 1):

As your own example states, Tag.create works but Tags.findAll doesn't. Have you tried Tag.findAll()? I use init for defining models but IIRC you should match the variable name to the table name.

Comment: Yeah i did that, and it hasn't changed anything. "Tags" variable is just a pointer to the model object, which holds the name of the table (Tag). Also, psql automatically adds the "s" in the end of the table name i think

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).